# undefined method `error_messages_for' for #<#<Class:0x3981390>:0x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

problem like this:

> undefined method `error_messages_for' for #<#:0x3a4f700>

My English is very rubbish, who can help me solve the problem? thanks

Comment: as already told, you need to post the code that is causing the error.

Answer (score 2):

`Error messages for` was removed in rails 3. It was extracted to a plugin, 
don't remember exactly what the plugin was called but it's in the rails 
GitHub repo. Rails has changed massively since 1.0.

Check this [Error messages for replacement](http://www.emersonlackey.com/article/rails3-error-messages-for-replacement).